# Is it right way to check CRUD Permission in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lwc-oss

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class CheckPermission extends LightningElement() {

    areAccountVisible = false;

        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })

        wiredData({data, error}){

            if(data){
     
                this.areAccountVisible = data.queryable;
            }
     
            if(error){
     
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can check like this too, but if you are using apex to do DMLs then you will have to do a check on Apex too. Also you need to write your logic after `this.areAccountVisible = data.queryable;` only, as `wire` methods are async in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @NagendraSingh